# Thread interference with each other in their execution (using Handler) in Android

Tags: android

In my App code I've extended the Button view (say it as DigiButton ) and overridden the onDraw() method. In onDraw() method I am setting the button text to some counter value. This counter value is decremented by 1 for every 500 ms by the Handler object (I am using Handler.run() method to update the counter value).

Now I've created two instances of "DigiButton" with different initial values of counter in "DigiComponent" class. "DigiComponent" has a button whose onClick event starts running both the threads.

I see some delay in the counter value update(on both the instances). I thought that each of the thread is interfering with the other thread execution. To confirm this I just started running only one "DigiButton" instance. Then the counter value got updated correct. Below is my code:

```
   class DigiButton extends Button{

        private int counter;

        private Runnable handleRunnable;

        DigiButton(Context context,int val){
          super(context);
          counter = val;
          initialize();
        }

       private void initialize(int val){ 
          digiHandler = new Handler();
          handleRunnable = new Runnable(){
          public void run(){

          }          
       };
       }

      private void updateCounter(){ 
         counter++;
         if(counter>0){
           runCounter();
         }
      }


       public void runCounter(){
            digiHandler.postDelayed(handleRunnable, 500);
       }


        @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){       
        super.onDraw(canvas);               
        setText(counter);
    }


   }



 public class DigiComponent extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    DigiButton thread1, thread2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        thread1 = new DigiButton(this,30000);
        thread2 = new DigitButton(this,20000);
        Button test = new Button(this);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.addView(thread1);
        layout.addView(thread2);
        layout.addView(test);
        test.setClickListener(this);
        setContentView(layout);
    }


   public void onClick(View v){
     thread1.runCounter();
     thread2.runCounter();
   }
 }
```

Is that my guess of thread execution interference is correct? If so how to avoid this? Is it something wrong with my thread handling code?

Note: This delay in counter value update is worse when I press "Home" button to go out of the App and I open the App again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not separate threads. These are `Runnable`s scheduled to run on the main UI thread. It gets worse when you press home because you are adding more and more `Runnable`s to the queue (that reschedule themselves).

You should look into `AsyncTask`s with the use of `AsyncTask.publishProgress` or just use a basic `Thread`.